# Password for "public CV"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, password

I'd like to create my public CV, but make it visible to only a handful of people (ie: people I send my electronic word CV to, which could include the URL of my SO public CV), making it semi-public.

Would it be possible to add a password to access it? This way I could put the URL, and the passcode to access it when I send my CV; and I could change it if I ever don't want those recruiters to see it anymore.

I guess I could create my CV in something like `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/[myPassCode]`, but it would be better to have a friendly url and a page that asks for the passcode before rendering it (kinda like the access to the private beta of SO last year)

**Edit**: Jeff argues that Google won't index it if it's unlinked, but Tom says it could do it anyway (and provides a link to prove it)

I still feel it'd be a nice feature, and 10 other people (at the time of this writing) agrees with me.

Perhaps a new feature request could be to provide an option to export it to html to do what Tom suggests?

Comment: I donno... There's something to be said for using a GUID as your "friendly" URL, and just changing it a few weeks after using it anywhere. Still friendly when it needs to be (in that if you send it somewhere you don't have to include a passcode along with it), but not *permanently* friendly.

Comment: @Shog9, are the public CV indexed by google? This was another concern of mine when requesting the feature

Comment: why would you want to not make it all available? For data you don't want on it, just leave it off is what I'd do

Comment: +1: I wouldn't password protect my CV myself, but I see the use in being able to have a CV available that can be shown to only a select few people, without having to worry about others being able to see it by guessing URLs/searching the web.

Comment: @Blixt, please upvote to attract attention and support it (besides commenting "+1" ;) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Public CVs are indexed by Google, but there is no public collection of all CV links. At least not one we publish.

Thus, I can't think of any way Google could index your public CV page unless you, or someone else, links to it from another source.

update: We now provide a time-limited URL on the publish tab. You can share this URL with whoever you like, and they can freely view your public CV for (n) days (even if it is not published), after which the link expires and is no longer valid.

Comment: +1. What's sad is that whenver I pull up the Google list; I keep getting different CVs, but none of which are mine -- even though I have them linked in my profile and on linked in. I'm guessing the rel='nofollow' is set?

Answer (score 9):

In response to Jeff, I wouldn't be the least surprised if google crawled Stackoverflow so aggressively that it somehow 'found' people's CV's.  [Them's sneaky](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/016288.html).

If you **really** want a password protected CV - I would publish it, save the HTML, and then unpublish it.  Put the HTML, with some formatting tweaks as needed, on a site you control.