# Option to make public resume non-indexable by Google?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, indexing

Other online resume services (Emurse, for example) let you designate your resume as publicly viewable but non-indexable by search engines.

There is some info in my CV that I do not want to become permanent public record.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28450

Comment: I like this idea, and am surprised that Jeff opposes it.  Why should an employer pay them to search when they can search the site on Google?  I don't think an option to be visible to employer searches on the site but not to the world via Google is unreasonable.

Comment: That said .. I do agree that if you don't want it "permanent public record" don't publish it on a web site!

Comment: Please make this optional

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... you want an option to include in the public CV page a `noindex` command for robots?  A la:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

This would prevent search engines that support the feature for indexing the page, even if someone links to it.  Google supports this, so googleing you would not return the public CV, but you could provide the link to people.  ***But*** who knows when/if someone will violate this "*rule*".

Comment: We'll add a checkbox to the "publish" tab that will control inserting this `meta` directive into your public CV page.

Comment: you really need a `/` before that `>` there... ;)

Answer (score 6):

> There is some info in my CV that I do not want to become permanent public record.

This is the purpose of the public cv privacy settings, where you can turn on or off (aka "HIDE") any section (and often sub-section) of your private cv. Can you describe the specific scenario that is not met by the existing privacy settings?

Solution:

1. Don't make your CV public.
2. Use the existing privacy settings; I still don't understand why you want your CV to be public if you *don't want it to be public*. Either turn off (aka "hide") the parts you don't want public using the provided privacy settings, or see #1.
3. Choose a GUID as your public CV URL and change it every week. Unless you link to it, there's no way this can get indexed. We don't link to it anywhere.

<s>update: We now provide a time-limited URL on the publish tab. You can share this URL with whoever you like, and they can freely view your public CV for (n) days (even if it is not published), after which the link expires and is no longer valid.</s> *this feature was removed*

Comment: Yes, I don't want to hide any sections. All of my private CV is the same CV that I want to make public. But I don't want my public CV to show up in a search like this one: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Acareers.stackoverflow.com+cv&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=1&cad=b. So, for all intents and purposes, Google should not know that my public CV exists. Emurse.com provides this option for CVs. I would like to have the same option here. If it's not possible on SO, I would be curious to know how Emurse is able to provide that option.

Comment: so you want your CV to be public but not public? Why not just NOT make it public and keep it private? I don't understand your request.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, he just wants it to be non-indexable by search engines, you know like adding rules to robots.txt so google and other search engines doesn't care about it even when they find it. Of course that's never guaranteed as some search engines just ignore robot rules. Maybe if only Google is the problem you can achieve this with webmaster tools.

Comment: the request seems reasonable (though I wouldn't use it myself), and beggs' solution is a good way to accomplish it.

Comment: "update: We now provide a time-limited URL on the publish tab." that seems like an overengineered solution, when all you have to do is give a boolean "add noindex meta tag" option

Comment: Is the time limited url still available with careers 2.0?  I want to share my profile with a couple of people but not have it sucked up by google right now and I'm wondering if this advice is still relevant/possible?

Comment: @Colin there are no longer time-limited URLs, but you can now make your profile public and check a box to make it not indexed by Google.

Comment: Does that option work properly?  If so then I'd say the UI is a little disconcerting because the tick box doesn't come up ticked and there's no real indication that it's not being indexed by Google.  In fact the whole quick saving of the data there made me nervous when I checked it.

Comment: @Colin sorry, it was temporarily broken.  It should be working now.

Answer (score 2):

> Public CVs are indexed by Google, but there is no public collection of all CV links. At least not one we publish.
>
> Thus, I can't think of any way Google could index your public CV page unless you, or someone else, links to it from another source.

[answered Nov 4 at 3:14](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28450/password-for-public-cv/28493#28493)
Jeff Atwood♦

---

> In response to Jeff, I wouldn't be the least surprised if google crawled Stackoverflow so aggressively that it somehow 'found' people's CV's. Them's sneaky.
>
> If you really want a password protected CV - I would publish it, save the HTML, and then unpublish it. Put the HTML, with some formatting tweaks as needed, on a site you control.

[answered Nov 4 at 3:18](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28450/password-for-public-cv/28494#28494)
Tom Ritter♦

---

As long as you don't publish a link to your CV online, you should be all right.

You could also *not* publish *until* you send a link to a potential employer.

Comment: But there's nothing stopping anyone from publishing a link, and once that happens it's game over.

Comment: Ether: there is nothing stopping you of changing your public address every fixed intervals of time to generate link rot.

Comment: How did these CVs end up in the Google index: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Acareers.stackoverflow.com+cv&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=1c443ffcb5a5cce1

Comment: @Kelso: those CVs have been published on other sites! For example, lets take the first CV that appears on Google: http://www.google.com/search?q=careers.stackoverflow.com%2Fsrid some fast googling tells us that he has been throwing that link to the wind like there is no tomorrow `</exageration>`. You can find links to his CV at  http://outdoorworkers.co.nz/233658-Twitter-Tweets-about-Careers-as-of-October-31-2009.html , http://www.jobsinforestry.co.nz/ and http://www.lineworkers.co.nz/ **at least**. Is not Google magic.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is assuming that your current employer is draconian.

Your public 'resume' is not a resume - it's a **CV** and isn't presence *doesn't* imply you're looking for a job anymore than an "About Me" page on a blog does.  I'm interested in people knowing [who I am](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/tomritter) - but I'm not looking for a job.  If your boss can't understand that... why would you *want* to keep working there?