# Can we have an optional robots.txt / meta robots disallow on the public CV's?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Option to make public resume non-indexable by Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/option-to-make-public-resume-non-indexable-by-google)

I like having a public CV I can link to employers- but I am concerned that searching for my name or my current employer's name on Google may bring up my CV as a result. It would be great if we could add a meta robots tag to disallow the CV from appearing on Google. Thoughts?

Comment: If you never link to it, it won't really "exist" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/option-to-make-public-resume-non-indexable-by-google

Comment: ahh, a dupe. i disagree though, once the link gets going around, it gets out there

Comment: But if nobody ever links to it, Google can't crawl it and it won't show in results.

Comment: True, but once it is linked, it will be out there forever.  Better if we can control when it is out there and when it isn't.

Comment: You can change the URL for a new one and it effectively destroys the other.