# What is the difference between public view and employer view in careers2.0?

Tags: support, jobs, cv

I remember in careers1.0 having seen the possibility to have section of the resume visible for the employer view (should you choose to unblock it), and not visible in the public view (should you publish it).
It was called a "**[public cv privacy setting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/option-to-make-public-resume-non-indexable-by-google/29883#29883)**".

In careers2.0, the only display option I can find is in a "experience" entry with a "Prevent this experience from appearing in header" option.

When selected, I still see this entry both in public and private view.

Is the notion of sections visible only for employers while non-visible for the public view still relevant in careers2.0? Is there still a "[public cv privacy setting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29765/option-to-make-public-resume-non-indexable-by-google/29883#29883)"?

Or is the employer view only there to acknowledged the fact you are willing to let employers to search for your CV (with additional SO-related details in it)?
(In which case, I suppose that the "Prevent this experience from appearing in header" is only there to prevent them to find an entry through Google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the public and the employer view is that the employer view shows what sort of work you're looking for and where you would consider working. Enabling it also shows that you are willing to be contacted by employers.

The "prevent this experience from appearing in the header" control is so that people have control over what shows in the header and what doesn't.

We no longer offer the ability to toggle the visibility of certain sections of your public profile. Having a profile does not necessarily mean you're looking for a job, rather, it's a great way to show off your accomplishments (with an added bonus that you can use it to find a job if you so choose). As such there is no need to hide anything from the public. In fact, anything you wouldn't want the general public to see probably shouldn't be seen by a prospective employer either, and the solution is to simply not include it.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. SO Careers is definitively not from me, then. Privacy settings made a lot of sense, and I had tons of details (names, references) that don't need to be visible publicly, but are needed by a potential employer.

Comment: @vonC I understand. There may also be a cultural difference here. My Dutch CV had a lot more information on it than my US CV does. While it's perfectly acceptable to leave references off in the States (to furnish them upon request) that may not be the case in France. There is another option: hide your public profile and only enable your employer view while you're actively looking for a job, and strip the sensitive information when you're not (and re-enable your public view at that point).

Comment: I agree with the process you mention, but I hope you agree with me it is rather cumbersome. My "frustration" comes from the fact I am not asking for a new feature, but for something that was actually implemented at first, and was very useful.

Comment: @vonC we removed the feature because it wasn't used very much (this is the first time since the feature was removed that someone has mentioned its demise) and we didn't feel the effort of reimplementing it in careers 2.0 was worth it - sounds like you got caught in the crossfire. No comment re edit being cumbersome :)