# Browsability and searchability of public CVs?

Tags: support, jobs

Are public CVs posted on careers browsable or searchable by the general public, or must we send the direct URL to the intended recipient?

If the latter, then I guess the "public"-ness of a CV is really limited to the possibility of it being indexed by search engines. Is that right?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28450

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29765

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public CVs are open and indexable by the public web, like any other public web page anywhere in the world.

However, **there is no master index of public CVs that we provide**.

Thus, the only way your public CV page would end up in Google indexes or Bing indexes (or <insert your favorite search engine here> ) is if someone links to it on the web somewhere, first.